# SQL summary queries

Tags: sql-server

I have an output from a SQL query. I want to refine the results to make it more meaningful.

The query returns the following results

```
Name    Date    Measure No    Measure Value    Measure Percent
--------------------------------------------------------------
xyz     30/06/18    1           33857               18
xyz     30/06/18    2           11056               45
xyz     30/06/18    4           46487               28
xyz     30/06/18    5           34376               48
abc     30/06/18    1           24982               27
abc     30/06/18    2           43234               45
abc     30/06/18    4           13791               25
abc     30/06/18    5           22261               20
lmn     30/06/18    1           45728               41
lmn     30/06/18    2           31480               48
lmn     30/06/18    4           32750               26
lmn     30/06/18    5           44771               36
```

I want to summarize further. I want to add the result of Measure 1 and Measure 2 to a temporary measure 3 for a particular name and date. The result of the query should be like this

```
Name    Date    Measure No  Measure Value   Measure Percent
-----------------------------------------------------------
xyz 30/06/18    1   33857   18
xyz 30/06/18    2   11056   45
xyz 30/06/18    3   44913   63
xyz 30/06/18    4   46487   28
xyz 30/06/18    5   34376   48
abc 30/06/18    1   24982   27
abc 30/06/18    2   43234   45
abc 30/06/18    3   68216   72
abc 30/06/18    4   13791   25
abc 30/06/18    5   22261   20
lmn 30/06/18    1   45728   41
lmn 30/06/18    2   31480   48
lmn 30/06/18    3   77208   89
lmn 30/06/18    4   32750   26
lmn 30/06/18    5   44771   36
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Add the query that produces the first result to your question. If its nothing more than a `SELECT` from a single table, specify that.

Comment: what will be the output from this two result set?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add rows with the new `Measure No` 3 as the sum of values and percentages of 1 and 2 by Name and Date, then this should do it for you:

```
SELECT [Name], [Date], [Measure No], [Measure Value], [Measure Percent]
FROM YourQueryResult

UNION ALL

SELECT [Name], [Date], 3, SUM([Measure Value]), SUM([Measure Percent])
FROM YourQueryResult
WHERE [Measure No] IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY [Name], [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need `union` or `union all` based on your output

```
select col1,col2.. from your 1stQueryoutput
union 

select col1,col2.. from your 2ndQueryoutput
```

or

```
select col1,col2.. from your 1stQueryoutput
union all

select col1,col2.. from your 2ndQueryoutput
```